# Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error (after the data is received from the dummy server)

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

This the relevant code

```
class Blog extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    selectedPostId: null
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(response => {
      const updatedDat = response.data
      const updatedData = []
      for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
      updatedDat[i].author = "Max";
      updatedDat[i].key = i;
      updatedData.push(updatedDat[i])
    }
      this.setState({posts:updatedData})
    }, function (error) {
    })
  }

  postClicked = (id) => {
    this.setState({selectedPostId: id})
  }
render () {
  const newPosts = this.state.posts.map(el => {
    return <Post key={el.id}
     title={el.title}
     author={el.author}
     clicked={this.postClicked(el.id)}/>
  })

    return (
        <div>
            <section className="Posts">
              {newPosts}
            </section>
            <section>
                <FullPost display={this.state.selectedPostId}/>
            </section>
            <section>
                <NewPost />
            </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Blog;
```

The error line in question is

```
 postClicked = (id) => {
> 30 |   this.setState({selectedPostId: id})
  31 | }
```

and

```
   clicked={this.postClicked(el.id)}/>
```

clicked is passed to the child component which is onCLick

```
 <article className="Post"  onClick={props.clicked}>
```

Now, I am able to fix the error when I do/change something like

```
clicked={() => this.postClicked(el.id)}
```

**[Question]:** Can someone tell me why do I receive the above error in first place and why does this (`clicked={() => this.postClicked(el.id)}`) is able to fix it.

Comment: That function updates the state via `setState()`, which triggers a re-render. As it re-renders, that function is called again, triggering another state update, and so on, repeatedly. The reason your fix works is because it creates a function that calls `postClicked()`, rather than actually calling `postClicked()`

Comment: @Jayce444 Thanks for your answer, So `this.postClicked()` calls a method which updates `setState()`  and as it re-renders, it again calls setState forming an infinite loop? But, when a function `{().postClicked(el.id)}` calls, wouldn't it call a method which again have setState and hence would similarly re-render stuff? How is different from that?

Comment: I don't what `{().postClicked(el.id)}` is, where are you getting that from? That's not valid syntax, nor in your question. If you're referring to the arrow function: `{() => this.postClicked(el.id)}` then when *that* function is called, yes it re-renders the state, but only when it's called, say via on click. It's not called when rendering, it's called in response to an action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your change to:

```
clicked={() => this.postClicked(el.id)})}
```

Fixes your issue, because instead of calling the function `this.postClicked()` immediately, you are creating a new function which will only be called when needed.

Comment: `this.postClicked(el.id)` calls a method which updates setState() and as it re-renders, it again calls setState forming an infinite loop? But, when a function `{().postClicked(el.id)}` calls, wouldn't it call a method which again have setState and hence would similarly re-render stuff? How is different from that? Can you please elaborate your answer?